# What happens when a game is a draw?

Tags: gwent

For example, I won the first round with 42:38, then I lost the second with 22:30 and the third round ends in 5:5.

All I was able to find was that the Nilfgaardian Empire will win any round that ends in a draw.

Besides that, will the game take previous rounds into consideration, is there a sudden death, or is the game simply a draw?
Also, how are the rewards distributed in case it really is a draw, and there is no winner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/3zoxyj/what_happens_in_a_nonnilfgaardian_draw_in_gwent/), when 2 non-Nilfgaardian players draw, you can choose to instantly rematch without consequence:

> What if it's the third round? Does the game officially end in a draw?
>
> Yes. You can instantly have a rematch without consequences.

This is further confirmed by the same thread stating that this is even the case in tournaments:

> Even tourney games that end with draw can be repeated

This [other Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/4nnc2j/gwent_what_happens_if_theres_a_draw_between_two/) also seems to confirm this:

> In a regular draw you get a chance to replay.

[This thread](http://forums.cdprojektred.com/forum/en/gwent/general-discussions-aa/6912510-ties-should-not-give-both-players-a-round-win) from the official Gwent forums claims with respect to awards:

> The only strange thing is, if your whole match ends in a tie it counts as a win-win on endscreen, but doesn't give any rewards to anyone.

So to summarize:

**A tie is considered a win for both players, but there are no rewards provided. You are also given the opportunity to play an entirely new match against the same opponent.**

Comment: So do we replay the whole match or do we get 'one more round' with the cards left in the deck? I ask because in the first statement you use 'rematch' and in the last there is 'another round'.

Comment: @Fotti I would go with the more specific "other round", especially since that guide seems to be a more reputable source than Reddit. I tried to convey that in my summary, but I can make that clearer if you think it would help others in the future.

Comment: This answer is referring to the gwent minigame inside the Witcher game, not to the standalone Gwent game which is what the question was about

Comment: Ah, @blgt you're correct for the last link, and I'll edit that now, however I believe the other links are still referring to the standalone Gwent

Comment: @blgt Yes, I wrote my comment just before checking out that guide, where I was a bit confused.

Comment: @blgt edited, now using a stronger source from the Gwent forums. Hopefully this is now accurate :D

Comment: That thread is a bit old so probably outdated. I'm quite sure you *do* get the daily progress reward

Comment: Interesting, I admittedly don't play the game, but feel free to update my answer or post a new answer if you find new information that you think is relevant or trumps the sources I found (which are ~1 year old)